# Build React app generate static files with chunk suffix

Tags: reactjs

I have create a react app using below command
npx create-react-app my-app

Now when I am building the app for production using below command
npm run build

It generate below files with suffix.

`build\static\js\1.82dafdb5.chunk.js`
`build\static\js\runtime~main.229c360f.js`
`build\static\js\main.a27c0d6d.chunk.js`
`build\static\css\main.c2586263.chunk.css`

I am looking how can i avoid random number and chunk suffix  in file name. And is there any way to only have one js file so that instead of importing three js files I can have one js file to import.

Comment: The random number is there for a purpose (search for "cache busting"). And what's the specific provokes with having multiple files?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so does it create different chunks for only those files which have changed? If the part of the code is not changed the chunk name will be same as old one?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't having multiple file chunks a bad idea because it will increase the network call?

Comment: @rbansal any file whose content hasn't changed will have the same hash, yes.

Answer (score 3):

After digging around quite a bit, I found the Following solution which worked on Windows.

Install:

```
npm i --save-dev renamer replace-in-file
```

And replace package.json build with these

```
{
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run build-rename",
    "build-rename": "npm run build-rename-js && npm run build-rename-css && npm run build-fix-references",
    "build-rename-js": "renamer --find \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\./i\" --replace \"main.\" build\\static\\js\\*",
    "build-rename-css": "renamer --find \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\./i\" --replace \"main.\" build\\static\\css\\*",
    "build-fix-references": "npm run build-fix-sourcemap && npm run build-fix-index && npm run build-fix-serviceworker && npm run build-fix-assetmanifest",
    "build-fix-sourcemap": "npm run build-fix-sourcemap-js && npm run build-fix-sourcemap-css",
    "build-fix-sourcemap-js": "replace-in-file \"/sourceMappingURL=main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js\\.map/i\" \"sourceMappingURL=main.js.map\" build/static/js/main.js --isRegex",
    "build-fix-sourcemap-css": "replace-in-file \"/sourceMappingURL=main\\.[^\\.]+\\.css\\.map/i\" \"sourceMappingURL=main.css.map\" build/static/css/main.css --isRegex",
    "build-fix-index": "npm run build-fix-index-js && npm run build-fix-index-css",
    "build-fix-index-js": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js/i\" \"main.js?v=%npm_package_version%\" build/index.html --isRegex",
    "build-fix-index-css": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.css/i\" \"main.css?v=%npm_package_version%\" build/index.html --isRegex",
    "build-fix-serviceworker": "npm run build-fix-serviceworker-js && npm run build-fix-serviceworker-css",
    "build-fix-serviceworker-js": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js/i\" \"main.js\" build/service-worker.js --isRegex",
    "build-fix-serviceworker-css": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.css/i\" \"main.css\" build/service-worker.js --isRegex",
    "build-fix-assetmanifest": "npm run build-fix-assetmanifest-js && npm run build-fix-assetmanifest-css && npm run build-fix-assetmanifest-js-map && npm run build-fix-assetmanifest-css-map",
    "build-fix-assetmanifest-js": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js/i\" \"main.js\" build/asset-manifest.json --isRegex",
    "build-fix-assetmanifest-css": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.css/i\" \"main.css\" build/asset-manifest.json --isRegex",
    "build-fix-assetmanifest-js-map": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.js\\.map/i\" \"main.js.map\" build/asset-manifest.json --isRegex",
    "build-fix-assetmanifest-css-map": "replace-in-file \"/main\\.[^\\.]+\\.css\\.map/i\" \"main.css.map\" build/asset-manifest.json --isRegex"
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/821

Answer (score 2):

You can create new `webpack.config.js` file at the root of your project and do something like this:

```js
const path = require("path")
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    }, ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

But you need to modify your `package.json` also accordingly:

```js
...
    "build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle", 
    "build:react": "react-scripts build", 
    "build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js", 
...
```

Comment: Thanks Levon, I have made the changes and seems it creating build.min.js file instead of three js files. But it does not generate css file, do i have add in webpack.conf.js file.   Also when I tried to use the js file in html seems its not working. Below is the output of the build command

Comment: > webpack --config webpack.config.js
Version: webpack 4.19.1
Time: 846ms

                        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
build/static/js/bundle.min.js  8.88 KiB       0  [emitted]  bundle.js
Entrypoint bundle.js = build/static/js/bundle.min.js
[0] multi ./build/static/css/main.0dafed5a.chunk.css ./build/static/js/main.ba81719e.chunk.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./build/static/css/main.0dafed5a.chunk.css 1.11 KiB {0} [built]
[2] ./node_modules/css-loader!./build/static/css/main.0dafed5a.chunk.css 1.07 KiB 
[6] ./build/static/js/main.ba81719e.chunk.js 1.31

Comment: try to only run `build` script